# passportjs and passportlocal add users "Error: failed to serialize user into session"

Tags: database, node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I have followed the code here - > https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/tree/master/examples/express3 for add local authentication for users.

The problem is when I try to add users,

So I created this route

```
app.get('/signup', function(req,res){
  res.render('/signup');
});

app.post('/signup', function(req,res){
  var body = req.body;
  users.push(body);
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Then the page w the form It's

```
form(method='POST', action='/signup')
 input(type='text', name='username', placeholder='username')
 input(type='text', name='password', placeholder='password')
 button.btn Register
```

The dummy DB It's the one on the example

```
users = [
  {id:1, username: 'test', password:'papapa'}
];
```

So when I send the info w the form, all goes ok, but when I try to log in with the new created user, tells me "Error: failed to serialize user into session"

the serializeUser is this

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user being pushed in the POST /signup route will not have an ID, which the examples serialization code expects.

Change it to something like this, and it should work.

```
app.post('/signup', function(req,res){
  var body = req.body;
  body.id = users.length;
  users.push(body);
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

(Note that this is an example only, and not recommended for "real" apps.)

Comment: and w is the recommended way to manage db and add users identifycation ?

Comment: there is no recommended way, do whatever makes sense for your application.  a good start is using a real database to persist data :)

Comment: I can't found a good working example of one, looks like I will have to switch to raisl cause database integration it's so easy

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are missing the session serializer. Take a look to https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport, section 'Sessions'.

Basically, you need two functions, to save the current user into the session (passport.serializeUser) and to read it back (passport.deserializeUser).

Comment: I followed this example ->  https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/tree/master/examples/express3, so that methods exists. I have to call them on my method ? app.post('/signup'..... ???

Comment: No, you don't need to call them directly, just provide the functions to passport.[de]serializeUser(). Howerver, I still thinks there is something wrong with your serialize function. Looking at passport code (https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/passport/index.js#L281 ), that error is fired when there is no serializer() function registered.

Comment: I add the methods for serialize